# how dynamically add many label with different name into scrollview

Tags: xcode, ios7, xcode5

Below is my code...to generate many label for Quiz App to show answer

```
for (NSInteger i = 0, y = 50; i < 3 ; i++, y += 30) {
    UILabel *nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 50, 100, 25)];
    _optoin1 =  [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)]; _op1.text= _optoin1;
    nameLabel.text =_optoin1;
    [_myscrollView addSubview:nameLabel];
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    key++;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

key is used get next columnvalue from db.It generate four label..

```
            for (NSInteger i = 0, y = 50; i < 4 ; i++, y += 30)
            {
                UILabel *nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, y, 100, 25)];
                _optoin1 =  [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *)              sqlite3_column_text(statement, key)];
                nameLabel.tag = labl_id;
                nameLabel.text =_optoin1;
                [_myscrollView addSubview:nameLabel];
                //sqlite3_finalize(statement);
                key++;
                labl_id++;
            }
```